# Holder equivalent metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, holder-spaces

Suppose we have a compact metrizable space $X$ and two metrics $d,h$ such that there is $a\in (0,1)$ and $c>0$ with $$h(x,y)\leq d(x,y)\leq c h(x,y)^a.$$

Can we deduce that $d,h$ are Holder equivalent for some $b\in (0,1)$?

Meaning $$c_1h(x,y)^b\leq d(x,y)\leq c_2 h(x,y)^b$$ for some $c_1,c_2>0?$

It seems a bit weird to hold whenever $d(x,y)<1$.

Thank you!

Comment: I think not, for what if $h(x,y)=d(x,y)$?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote your formulae correctly? In think, in several places, $d$ should be $h$. The usual definition of Holder equivalence would require the identity map to be bi-Holder (possibly with different exponents).

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are right for the typo. However, can we have the same Holder exponents?

Comment: Such defined Hölder equivalence with $b<1$ not necessary is an equivalence. For instance, if $d=h$ is the usual metric on $[0,1]$, then the first inequality in the question holds for each $a\in (0,1)$, but $d$ is not equivalent to $h=d$.